# Is code optimization off topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

On this question...

*[Two sum algorithm variant - Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106663/two-sum-algorithm-variant-optimization)*

...someone left this comment:

> Optimizing working code is off topic on here. This site is for fixing broken code. You can try codereview.stackexchange for optimizing code.

Is that really true? Personally, I'd love to see questions about optimization or code improvements in general on stackoverflow.com. Are we really *only* about fixing broken code?

Comment: No, we're about expert answers to questions.  If code is broken and we can help that's a huge plus, but that isn't and shouldn't be our focus.

Comment: From what I've seen, the only performance/optimization questions involving working code that are safe from closure/migration to CR are the ones that are phrased as, "Why is A faster/slower than B?" and backed up with evidence.

Comment: Not off topic, but a very strong selector for bad questions.  That fail at the most basic premise of such a question, they don't say how much faster it needs to be.

Comment: I hope its not ever going to be deemed off-topic, as it can spawn this kind of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array

Comment: The specific example is textbook "Too broad". _"I have this working code, but I want it to be faster. Please help."_